# IIS redirect with regex

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a url like
/fl-1/page/name.aspx

to

/fl-1/pages/name.aspx

Where "1" and "name" are variable. I'm trying with this expression

```
  <rule name="D17" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/fl-([0-9]+)/page/([^/]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/fl-{R:1}/pages/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
  </rule>
```

but when trying this I get this error:
Error HTTP 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
Expression "/fl-{R:1}/pages/{R:2}" cannot be expanded.

EDIT:
when testing the url /fl-1/page/name.aspx with this regex ^/fl-([0-9]+)/page/([^/]+)$ I get two matches so in theory R1 and R2 should be available here.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm testing my regex here http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx using the sample url I provided and I get 2 matches, not one as noted on the other question you referenced. I don't think it's the same problem.